# Amazon Lex slots are filled but Lex responds to lambda said it is still DialogCodeHook when it should be FulfillmentCodeHook after all slots filled

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

The code I wrote in Lambda used to work fine and now today, it just doesn't work. The code I wrote are just validation of slots for Amazon Lex to make sure that the user fill all the information. After the user filled all the information, Lex should send a response like this:

```json
{
    "sessionId": "526322052651484",
    ...
    "sessionState": {
      "sessionAttributes": {},
      "intent": {
        "name": "BookTestDrive",
        "slots": {
          "ContactDetails": {
            "shape": "Scalar",
            "value": {
              "originalValue": "mail@mail.com",
              "resolvedValues": [],
              "interpretedValue": "mail@mail.com"
            }
          },
          "FirstName": {
            "shape": "Scalar",
            "value": {
              "originalValue": "Buln",
              "resolvedValues": [
                "Bula"
              ],
              "interpretedValue": "Buln"
            }
          },
          "Date": {
            "shape": "Scalar",
            "value": {
              "originalValue": "14-03-2024",
              "resolvedValues": [
                "2024-03-14"
              ],
              "interpretedValue": "2024-03-14"
            }
          }
        },
        "state": "ReadyForFulfillment",
        "confirmationState": "None"
      },
      "originatingRequestId": "a13fd06a-bc03-4a80-94f9-8b65e7b2edb2"
    },
    "invocationSource": "FulfillmentCodeHook",
    ...
  }
```

Instead today it response with this one instead

```json
{
    "sessionId": "526322052651839",
    ...
    "sessionState": {
      "sessionAttributes": {},
      "activeContexts": [],
      "intent": {
        "confirmationState": "None",
        "name": "BookTestDrive",
        "slots": {
          "ContactDetails": {
            "shape": "Scalar",
            "value": {
              "originalValue": "email@mail.com",
              "resolvedValues": [],
              "interpretedValue": "email@mail.com"
            }
          },
          "FirstName": {
            "shape": "Scalar",
            "value": {
              "originalValue": "Bunleap",
              "resolvedValues": [],
              "interpretedValue": "Bunleap"
            }
          },
          "Date": {
            "shape": "Scalar",
            "value": {
              "originalValue": "today",
              "resolvedValues": [
                "2023-07-25"
              ],
              "interpretedValue": "2023-07-25"
            }
          }
        },
        "state": "InProgress"
      },
      "originatingRequestId": "47dd31f5-0119-42c1-9d22-89bf05d44d86"
    },
    ...
    "invocationSource": "DialogCodeHook",
  }
```

Here is the lambda python code:

```py
import boto3
import random

def validate_booking(slots):
    if not slots['FirstName']:
        return {
            'isValid': False,
            'invalidSlot': 'FirstName'
        }

    if not slots['ContactDetails']:
        return {
            'isValid': False,
            'invalidSlot': 'ContactDetails'
        }

    if not slots['Date']:
        return {
            'isValid': False,
            'invalidSlot': 'Date'
        }

    return {'isValid': True}


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)

    bot = event['bot']['name']
    slots = event['sessionState']['intent']['slots']
    intent = event['sessionState']['intent']['name']

    validate_result = validate_booking(slots)

    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table("CarBookTestDrive")
    
    if event['invocationSource'] == 'DialogCodeHook':
        if not validate_result['isValid']:
            if 'message' in validate_result:
                response = {
                    "sessionState": {
                        "dialogAction": {
                            "slotToElicit": validate_result['invalidSlot'],
                            "type": "ElicitSlot"
                        },
                        "intent": {
                            "name": intent,
                            "slots": slots
                        }
                    },
                    "messages": [
                        {
                            "contentType": "PlainText",
                            "content": validate_result['message']
                        }
                    ]
                }
            else:
                response = {
                    "sessionState": {
                        "dialogAction": {
                            "slotToElicit": validate_result['invalidSlot'],
                            "type": "ElicitSlot"
                        },
                        "intent": {
                            "name": intent,
                            "slots": slots
                        }
                    }
                }
        else:
            response = {
                "sessionState": {
                    "dialogAction": {
                        "type": "Delegate"
                    },
                    "intent": {
                        'name': intent,
                        'slots': slots
                    }
                }
            }

    if event['invocationSource'] == 'FulfillmentCodeHook':
        
        message = f"Thanks {event['sessionState']['intent']['slots']['FirstName']['value']['interpretedValue']}, We will contact you shortly to confirm the drive test."

        response = {
            "sessionState": {
                "dialogAction": {
                    "type": "Close"
                },
                "intent": {
                    "name": intent,
                    "slots": slots,
                    "state": "Fulfilled"
                }

            },
            "messages": [
                {
                    "contentType": "PlainText",
                    "content": message
                }
            ]
        }
        
        table.put_item(Item={
            'TestDriveID': str(random.randint(1000,9999)),
            'FirstName': event['sessionState']['intent']['slots']['FirstName']['value']['interpretedValue'],
            'ContactDetails': event['sessionState']['intent']['slots']['ContactDetails']['value']['interpretedValue'],
            'Date': event['sessionState']['intent']['slots']['Date']['value']['interpretedValue']
        })
    

    return response
```

I just want the "invocationSource" to be FulfillmentCodeHook when everything is fulfilled rather than being DialogCodeHook.

Comment: reducing the code to a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might help (both you and others) to isolate the problem...